# Handle Clicks on Android AppWidget/RemoteViews

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget, remoteview

i'm trying to implement customizable widgets by drawing a Bitmap and applying it to an ImageView. Visualization works fine but I can't intercept the touches depending on the area clicked by the user. I've read all the questions that have already been asked here and it seems like it's impossible to implement. But I was wondering if it's impossible how does KWGT or Zooper dynamically intercept clicks ? Anyone have any idea how they got around this problem ?

Comment: Are you asking about intercepting clicks on different areas of the the Bitmap, or on some other area?

Comment: Yes, in different areas of the Bitmap.

Comment: Have you tried placing transparent clickable views over the top of your bitmap?

Comment: No but now that you mention it I could use some transparent bitmaps as margins to adjust the position of the widget. You enlightened me, thank you.